# How to set timeout in Firebird with HeidiSQL?

Tags: sql, firebird, heidisql, firebird-4.0

I have Firebird 4.0, querying from HeidiSQL. After just two nested joins, HeidiSQL returns:

> SQL Error (335544794): [FireDAC][Phys][FB]operation was cancelled
> Statement level timeout expired.

I believe the query would've run just over a second. After googling a little bit, I found out to change the "statement timeout" with `SET STATEMENT TIMEOUT 1000 SECOND;`. For some reason, the message still appears, as if Firebird ignores my statement.

Full query in HeidiSQL:

```
SET STATEMENT TIMEOUT 1000 SECOND;

SELECT FIRST 100 * FROM STAGE_TABLE
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIM_TABLE ON STAGE_TABLE.ID = DIM_TABLE.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN FACT_TABLE ON STAGE_TABLE.ID = FACT_TABLE.ID;
```

Select plus only the first join takes about half a second, adding the second join runs into expired statement. It seems like HeidiSQL or Firebird just ignores my first SQL command. How can I fix that?

Comment: You can try another DB client, like DBeaver

Comment: Are you able to check if there is already a lower timeout set at the database level ? https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-management-timeouts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to reproduce this. The problem is that HeidiSQL has a (default) query timeout setting of `30` (no unit), and it seems this gets passed on execute of a statement without taking into account that Firebird expects milliseconds.

In other words, Firebird receives an instruction to execute the statement with a timeout of 30 *milliseconds*, which is pretty short. This then results in the *"operation was cancelled Statement level timeout expired."* error.

That is because a non-zero timeout passed on execute takes precedence over the session-level statement timeout you set with `SET STATEMENT TIMEOUT` (though if it is higher than a non-zero database-level statement timeout, it will use the database-level statement timeout).

To fix this, in the session manager of HeidiSQL, select your Firebird server, go to the tab "Advanced" and in "Query timeout" enter `0` (for no statement-level timeout), or enter the desired timeout value (taking into account that it is in *milliseconds*).

[image: Screenshot of the Advanced tab of a Firebird database in the HeidiSQL Session Manager, the Query timeout setting is set to zero and hihglighted]

Comment: Ah, I completely forgot about timeout for particular statement at API level. Thanks for reminder.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.